# Kafka Connect separated logging

Tags: debugging, logging, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Currently we are using a couple of custom connetor plugins for our confluent kafka connect distributed worker cluster. One thing that bothers me for a long time is that kafka connect writes all logs from all deployed connectors to one File/Stream. This makes debugging an absolute nightmare. Is there a way to let kafka connect log the connectors in different Files/Streams?

Via the `connect-log4j.properties` I am able to let a specific class log to a different File/Stream. But this means that with every additional connector I have to adjust the `connect-log4j.properties`

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered Elasticsearch/Logstash?

Comment: Yes we took this into consideration. And if we dont find any other way this will be our solution. I cannot believe that kafka connect do not have any proper log handling

Comment: "proper log handling" meaning what? A separate file for every connector? Have you searched JIRA for this feature or otherwise created it? Seems like a useful idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka Connect does not currently support this. I agree that it is not ideal.

One option would be to split out your connectors and have a dedicated worker cluster for each, and thus separate log files.

Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka so you could [raise a JIRA](https://jira.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA/) to discuss this further and maybe contribute it back via a PR?

---

*Edit April 12, 2019:* See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-449%3A+Add+connector+contexts+to+Connect+worker+logs

Comment: Thanks for the update Robin! I will open a ticket like suggested. And in the meantime we will take the Logstash/Elasticsearch way.

Comment: Did you happen to create the JIRA, @Stephan? If so, can you share that, please?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @RobinMoffatt :)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Can we get connector wise log file by adding this `connector context` to `log4j.appender.connectAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/connect.log` ?

Answer (score 0):

I added this connector.context to log4j.appender.connectAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/connect.log but I was not able to get any connector log separately. Also, the name of the file is not formed with the connector name. It was formed with the variable name  - "connector.context"