# Kafka Connect Logs per connector

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am Using Kafka rest proxy to start confluent connector's but having a problem in reading error in logs all logs written in connect.stdout file
I need logs per connector in a seperate log file.

like JDBC-testTable-source.log, Cassandra-dump-sink.log so I can send it to end user

I have tried to grep command to separate logs from connect.stdout file 
and log4j file for logging

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka Connect Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52200664/kafka-connect-logging)

Comment: Confluent Rest Proxy doesn't interact with Connect... I think you're confusing just the standard Connect's REST API, which has nothing to do with Confluent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Apache Kafka 2.2 a worker logs everything to a single log file, with no indication per entry which connector it is from.

[KIP-449](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-449%3A+Add+connector+contexts+to+Connect+worker+logs) is due to be added in Apache Kafka 2.3 and will make it much easier to identify which log entry comes from which connector.

Comment: that's correct we cannot separate logs, but we can have some logs using i.e grep command on connect.stdout